# In a train of n wagons, at random m passengers enter choosing a wagon..

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Find the probability that:

$(a)$ In every wagon there is at most one passenger, if $m\leq n;$

$(b)$ In the $n$th wagon, there is exactly one passenger, if $m\leq n;$

$(c)$ In every wagon there is at least one passenger, if $m\geq n;$

My thoughts:

$(a)$ ${\binom{n}{m}m!}\over n^m$  (choose m wagons of  the n, permute the m wagons..)

$(b)$ ${m (n-1)^{m-1}}\over n^m$

$(c)$ $\binom{n}{1}\binom{n-1}{1}..\binom{n-m}{1}?$ thats to arrange one person in ever wagon, not sure how to make it arrange the remaining passengers... Need help with this last one.

Comment: for a and b i wrote, but am not sure if its correct.

Comment: The first two are right. The last is Inclusion/Exclusion, or you can look up Stirling Numbers of the Second Kind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the last one $$A={(x_1,x_2,...x_n); x_1+x_2+..+x_n=m; x_1,..x_n > 1 } $$
Therefore: $$A={(x_1,x_2,...x_n); x_1+x_2+..+x_n=m-n; x_1,..x_n > 0 } $$
$$|A|= \binom {m-1}{m-n}=\binom {m-1}{n-1}$$